# Samba server issues

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have setup a new linux box that I am tinkering with. One item that I have always setup is samba so that I can easily copy files to and from the server.

The reason I bring this topic up is I am not able to browse to the samba shares from my windows machine.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

The issue that I am having is when I start the server, the server starts, but in the /var/log/samba/smbd.log I get this error:

```
[2009/12/14 23:23:00,  0] smbd/server.c:456(smbd_open_one_socket)
smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use
```

Here is my smb.conf:

```
[global]
dns proxy = No
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
load printers = No
smb ports = 139
server string = WWW Server
unix password sync = yes
force group = mediauser
workgroup = WORKGROUP
force user = mediauser
domain master = Yes
encrypt passwords = yes
valid users = mediauser,devroot
realm = devstation
preferred master = Yes
directory mode = 777
wins support = Yes
hosts allow = 192.168.1.



    [video]
writeable = yes
path = /mediacenter/video
force directory mode = 0777
force create mode = 0777
create mask = 0777
comment = Video
directory mask = 0777
public = yes
    allow hosts = 192.168.1.
```

Comment: This is probably more suited to http://www.superuser.com than here.

Comment: Samba is a server - serverfault is likely to be better: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error message and it does not affect me, Samba is working well even with this error.

I found it disturbing when I discovered it last week, so I asked on IRC, and was told by two Samba developers to not worry about it.

To determine whether this error message is actually your problem, check which program is using the netbios-ssn port, just run:

`sudo lsof -i :139`

Cheers,
Nicolas